# Closing JiraClient properly

Tags: jira-rest-api

I am using this [plugin](https://github.com/rcarz/jira-client) to help my web-app communicate with Atlassian JIRA.

So my question -> Is there a proper way to close `net.rcarz.jiraclient.JiraClient` instance when I'm done with it?

I'm guessing leaving it be and creating a `client = new JiraClient(uri,creds)` when next user logs in is not a good idea...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JiraClient` doesn't keeps a connection open, it just uses the supplied credentials for each request. You don't have to close it. As far as I can tell, you a free to use multiple `JiraClient` concurrently.